# Delete customer orders over two years old from their last order date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I need to delete records older than two years for individual customers.
I am looking for an efficent solution because of number of rows in my table.

In the simplified example below I am looking to delete record Order_ID o3 as it is over two years old from customer_id 1 last order date which is 01/01/2022

Following is a simple view of my table

```
Order_ID    Customer_ID     Order_Date  
o1          1               01/01/2022  
o2          2               02/02/2022  
o3          1               01/01/2019
```

delete as it is over two years fro Customer#1's last order

```
o4          1               01/01/2021  
o5          2               01/08/2021
```

Comment: So would something with a date of 2020-07-01 *not* be deleted, because it's within 2 years of 2022-01-01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `MAX` date for each individual user in a subquery, and use the `DATEADD` function to get the date 2 years previous to the `MAX` (most recent order) date for each individual user and join on this to do deletions :

```
  delete t 
  from yourtable t
  inner join
  (
     select Customer_ID, DATEADD(year, -2, MAX(ORDER_DATE)) as order_date
     from yourtable
     group by Customer_ID
  ) x
  on t.Customer_ID = x.Customer_ID
  where t.ORDER_DATE < x.order_date
```

**Sample Data:**

```
Customer_ID ORDER_DATE
1           2019-06-13
1           2022-06-14
2           2022-01-01
2           2022-06-03
2           2019-01-01
3           2019-03-03
```

**Result:**

```
Customer_ID ORDER_DATE
1           2022-06-14
2           2022-01-01
2           2022-06-03
3           2019-03-03
```

Comment: Looks like it is working fine. Thank you. Any way to improve performance it takes over 2 mins to complete because of the size of the table?

Comment: @failsafe100 The first time you run it, it will take a while since you hadn't done the deletions before, but if you run this on a weekly or monthly basis, it should go much faster since you already did the initial deletions. If that is still problematic, you could modify to do it in batches based on specific ranges of employee ids. You could also look at your indexing on the table as well.

Comment: Thanks, will look at indexing. The data size will remain the same every time I run. This is down to another ETL process.

Comment: @failsafe100 Here are some other tips on how to improve deletion speed: [fastest-way-to-delete-large-number-of-records-in-sql-server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6238/fastest-way-to-delete-large-number-of-records-in-sql-server/)